Transaction not confirmed
I used python to write a program that performs swaps on solana using Jupiter V6 aggregator, the transaction gets signed and it gives a hash, but the transaction never gets confirmed and if use the hash to check on Solscan it says transaction not found. please how can i fix this problem?
I've been stuck for days.
my RPC urls;
RPC_URLS = [
"https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com",
"https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net",
"https://solana-api.projectserum.com",
"https://solana.public-rpc.com"

]
jupiter swap url;
jupiter_swap_url = "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap"
    swap_data = {
        "quoteResponse": quote_data,
        "userPublicKey": str(sender_keypair.public_key),
        "wrapUnwrapSOL": True,
        "asLegacyTransaction": True,
        "computeUnitPriceMicroLamports": 1000000         }


Can you show how you are sending the signed transaction, and if there are any errors show those too?

transaction.sign(sender_keypair)

Signing a transaction does not send it to the network. At this point, if you want help, readers will need much more information, such as the Python framework you're using (wherefrom did you get the implemenation of sign(), for instance), a complete code example, and the full stacktrace of the error you're receiving, if applicable. I think you just need to figure out how to send your signed transaction though.
